# I am having issue while keeping the same slug if we don't change title while updating

Tags: laravel

I am having issue while keeping the same slug if we don't change title while updating, slug take the value of title. I have made a function to create slug. But when i update the same function automatically changes slug because it already exists in DB.

```
public function createSlug($title, $id = 0)
{
    $slug = str_slug($title);
    $allSlugs = $this->getRelatedSlugs($slug, $id);
    if (! $allSlugs->contains('slug', $slug)){
        return $slug;
    }

    $i = 1;
    $is_contain = true;
    do {
        $newSlug = $slug . '-' . $i;
        if (!$allSlugs->contains('slug', $newSlug)) {
            $is_contain = false;
            return $newSlug;
        }
        $i++;
    } while ($is_contain);
}

// slug function
protected function getRelatedSlugs($slug, $id = 0)
{
    return Post::select('slug')
    ->where('slug', 'like', $slug.'%')
    ->where('id', '<>', $id)
    ->get();
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do? I am afraid I dont completely understand your question

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to create a function for that. Just validation will be enough.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

    $validator = $request->validate([
        'slug' => ['required''unique:post'],
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $generate_extension = Str::random(3);;
    }
    $newSlug = str_slug($request->title).'-'.$generate_extension;
```

Then assign the slug.

```
$post->slug  = $newSlug;
```

In order to keep the same slug you can check if title is changed;

```
    if($post->slug != str_slug($request->title)){
        $post->slug = str_slug($request->title);
    }
```

or

```
    if($post->title != $request->title){
        $post->slug = str_slug($request->title);
    }
```

Comment: The slug function is create slug for me if i change the title it works automatically change the slug which is good and i want it. but in case if i dont change title and make other changes to post then it also change slug also like abc-1 which is the only problem i am having, any idea to fix it?

Comment: Check the answer again. If it doesn't help i don't know your answer.